# SkyDive Equipment

Tags: gear

In 2009 I successfully completed the [AFF course](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_freefall), after a stop due to the birth of my son I'm going to resume regular activity.

I currently have 31 jumps, all carried out by renting the equipment, and now I want to buy my own equipment (parachute).

**What equipment would be considered adequate to last two years, expected about 200 jumps?** What specifications should I keep in mind while reviewing parachutes?

I would like to hear an opinion different from that given by the school that recommended, among other things, used equipment.

Answer (score 4):

Your school should have the best knowledge of how you fly, but a good rule of thumb is

- absolutely no wing-loadings over 1-1 ( wing-loading is Exit weight/ canopy size).

So if you weigh 170, a 190 should be your smallest parachute.

Most beginners buy used - and the classifieds on dropzone.com have lots of stuff for sale.  I'd stick with stuff made since the late 90s unless price is a real issue.  You definitely want a square main - for example sabre (1/2) pilot triathlon spectre Safire.